# Message redistribution on ArtemisMQ 2.x does not work

Tags: hornetq, activemq-artemis

I would like to enable message redistribution on my 2-nodes cluster with static hosts. But it does not seem to work.

1) I have 10 producers that write to the queue "MyTestQueue" on node 1 (but no consumers).
2) I have 1 consumer on node 2 (but no producers) that consumes messages from node 2.

I expect that node 1 will redistribute the messages to node 2 where the consumer exists, but it does not. The message count on node 1 is still equal the amount of messages that was sent to node 1.

I have the following configuration in my broker.xml that sets `forward-when-no-consumers` to false.
I also have set `redistribution-delay` to a value of zero.

```
<jms xmlns="urn:activemq:jms">
    <queue name="MyTestQueue"/>
</jms>
...
<cluster-connections>
      <cluster-connection name="my-test-cluster">
           <address>jms</address>
           <connector-ref>server0-connector</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <forward-when-no-consumers>false</forward-when-no-consumers>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <confirmation-window-size>1024</confirmation-window-size>
            <static-connectors>
                <connector-ref>server1-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
        </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>
    ...
    <address-settings>
         <address-setting match="#">
             <redelivery-delay>5000</redelivery-delay>
             <redelivery-delay-multiplier>3</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
             <max-redelivery-delay>10000</max-redelivery-delay>
             <max-delivery-attempts>10</max-delivery-attempts>
             <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>
             <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
             <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
             <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
        </address-setting>
    </address-settings>
```

How can I get the message redistribution to work?

Answer (score 2):

This might be related to a known [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1351). There is a situation on which the broker fails to load balance the messages if they don't contain the application properties field.

Could you, please, try with that?

Comment: Thanks! Could you please specify what kind of application properties I have to set and where? On the client? In the broker.xml?

Comment: @Rox Set some application properties on the messages you are sending. Anything should work. Just do not send the message completely without any application properties.

Comment: @user7610: Oh, I see! I will try to set a string property on the message and see if it works. Will get back here with the result.

Comment: @user7610: Now I have tested and unfortunately it did not work for me. :-( The messages are still not redistributed to a node with consumers.

Comment: Can you provide additional details about your configuration and the steps you took for configuring the cluster? For example, did you create the queue on all nodes? I compared your configuration with mine and mine is considerably simpler. In my case I configured it via command-line.

Comment: @user7610: Yes, the queue exists on both nodes. I have also fully studied their example at: https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/queue-message-redistribution and it seem to work sometimes and simetimes not. I does not work if I send the messages to the first broker and try to consume them on the second one. But it does work if I send them to the first broker and then close the second one, but that is not what I want. I want to consume the messages from the second broker only after sending them to the first broker node.

Comment: What I mean is that it only works if both brokers do have consumers and one of the consumers is being closed. Then the messages will redistribute. But if the initial state after starting up the Artemis cluster and my application is that the first node only has a producer and the second one a consumer, it does not work. Message redistribution only seems to work if a sessions was closed previosly.

Comment: @Rox This sounds like a bug. Could you please report it to the Artemis issue tracker, at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS? (Requires creating account on the Jira). If not, I or maybe otavio021 can try to fill it when we have some time.

Comment: Hi @Rox Could you explain what properties you added that make it work ?
I facing same problem, My cluster(2 broker) user replication colocated but it does not redistribution messages to other broker

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things...

- What version of Artemis are you using?  Have you tried reproducing this with version 2.2.0?
- What kind of client are you using (e.g. JMS, AMQP, STOMP, etc.)?
- Do you have a reproducible test-case (e.g. a modified version of one of the examples shipped with Artemis)?
- The configuration element <forward-when-no-consumers> is not valid in Artemis (although it was in older versions of HornetQ).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<address>jms</address>` from cluster connection configuration - each cluster connection only applies to addresses that match the specified address. And make sure that you're using compatible client because messages from 1.x clients to 2.x cluster are lost when the are load balanced to nodes with matching consumers.

[Here's official, working example of ActiveMQ Artemis configuration with symmetric cluster, on demand load balancing and message redistribution](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/2.3.0/examples/features/clustered/queue-message-redistribution)