# Artemis cluster message redistribution doesn't seem to work

Tags: cluster-computing, message-queue, activemq-artemis

I'm using Artemis 2.6.3. I've created 2 nodes in a symmetric topology.

The producer and consumers are handled by Spring Broker Relay described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-message-flow). It writes to
address `/topic/notification/username/lual` (multicast) and the generated queues are non durable.

The consumer(s) only receive the message if attached to Node 1 (where messages are produced). I can have one attached to node 1 receiving the messages and other to node 2 not receiving the messages. IF both on Node 2 none receive the messages.

I think message redistribution is not working but cannot figure out why. I followed the examples and available documentation.
I added all the configs I have below.

Generated diagram:

[image: Diagram of the cluster]

`broker.xml`:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>$HOSTNAME</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 0,47 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 2148000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>2148000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->



    <connectors>
        <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
        <connector name="artemis">tcp://$HOSTNAME:61616</connector>
    </connectors>



      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->

      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->

         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://$HOSTNAME:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://$HOSTNAME:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://$HOSTNAME:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://$HOSTNAME:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://$HOSTNAME:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <cluster-user>adminCluster</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>adminCluster</cluster-password>

      <broadcast-groups>
        <broadcast-group name="artemis-broadcast-group">
            <jgroups-file>jgroups-stacks.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>artemis_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
            <!--<broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>-->
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
        </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
        <discovery-group name="artemis-discovery-group">
          <jgroups-file>jgroups-stacks.xml</jgroups-file>
          <jgroups-channel>artemis_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
          <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
        </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-connections>
        <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
          <address>#</address>
          <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
          <check-period>1000</check-period>
          <connection-ttl>5000</connection-ttl>
          <min-large-message-size>50000</min-large-message-size>
          <call-timeout>5000</call-timeout>
          <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
          <retry-interval-multiplier>2.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
          <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
          <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
          <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
          <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
          <forward-when-no-consumers>false</forward-when-no-consumers>
          <max-hops>1</max-hops>
          <confirmation-window-size>32000</confirmation-window-size>
          <call-failover-timeout>30000</call-failover-timeout>
          <notification-interval>1000</notification-interval>
          <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
          <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="artemis-discovery-group"/>
        </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>


      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
            <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>

   </core>
</configuration>
```

`jgroups.xml`:

```xml
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/JGroups-3.0.xsd">
   
   <UDP ip_ttl="8"
      max_bundle_size="64000"
      ip_mcast="false"
      thread_pool.enabled="true"
      thread_pool.min_threads="1"
      thread_pool.max_threads="10"
      thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
      thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
      thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
      thread_pool.rejection_policy="run"

      oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
      oob_thread_pool.min_threads="1"
      oob_thread_pool.max_threads="8"
      oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
      oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
      oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
      oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="run"
      
      bind_addr="match-interface:eth.*"
      receive_interfaces="eth0"
   />
   
   <BPING
      dest="$BROADCAST_ADDR"
      port_range="10" 
      bind_port="8555"/>
      
   <MERGE2 max_interval="30000"
      min_interval="10000"/>
      
   <FD_SOCK/>
   
   <FD timeout="10000" max_tries="5" />
   
   <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
   
   <BARRIER />
   
   <pbcast.NAKACK
      use_mcast_xmit="false"
      retransmit_timeout="300,600,1200,2400,4800"
      discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
      
   <UNICAST />
   
   <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000"
      max_bytes="400000"/>
      
   <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="3000"
      view_bundling="true"/>
      
   <FC max_credits="2000000"
      min_threshold="0.10"/>
      
   <FRAG2 frag_size="60000"  />
   
   <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
   
   <pbcast.FLUSH/>
   
</config>
```

The DEBUG log is [here](https://paste.ee/p/kBOaY)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the cluster is forming correctly? Do you see logging indicating that the cluster bridges have successfully connected?  Also, why are you using JGroups for clustering?  Why not simply use the default multicast configuration?

Comment: Attached a log. From the diagram the cluster seem to be formed. In the log I also see  AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge 2 times. JGroups it's just because I want to learn. Currently I'm not using multicast, instead I use UDP broadcast (not so efficient), but It's less hassle in docker (I guess).

Comment: FWIW, when I say "multicast" I'm talking about "UDP multicast" which is the same thing as "UDP broadcast" as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I can't tell what's going on based on the information you've provided. Have you tried simplifying the use-case any (e.g. removing Spring Broker Relay from the equation or running both brokers on the same machine using static clustering)?  Could you work up a reproducible test-case?

Comment: Well...multicast works on a specific address range while broadcast for a CIDR /24 will have and address that end with .255 (but this is not important for the topic). If you are comfortable with docker I guess I can share the apachemq-artemis part in github. I suppose you have an easy way to create STOMP producer and consumers to test, no? As far as I understood redistribution works with Core Bridge connection and for what I saw it seems to be established. I think the clusters discovery process is working fine.

Comment: Maybe is something related with STOMP message that the producer send. I'll try to activate debug logging to try to figure out what's happening. Also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698399/message-redistribution-on-artemismq-2-x-does-not-work but no good answer.

Comment: If message redistribution was completely broken it would show up in test-suite failures and failures in the examples shipped with the broker which demonstrate it. My hunch is that there's a nuance here which is causing the unexpected behavior. My recommendation would be to start with something really simple (e.g. one of the examples like `queue-message-redistribution`) which you can verify that it works and add complexity from there. For example, move the brokers from the example to different machines and confirm it still works, then introduce JGroups, then Spring, etc. You'll learn a lot too.

Comment: Attached a debug log. We can see that both nodes request information about the queues and receive that info about  address=notif.a5e1e9cc-d92a-11, but not the others...I suppose is because of that that he don't do the message redistribution. But don't understand why he don't send all the addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is the value used for `address` in your `cluster-connection`:

```
<address>#</address>
```

You're treating the `address` here as if it supports wild-card matching when it, in fact, does not. [The documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/clusters.html#configuring-cluster-connections) makes this clear (emphasis mine):

> Each cluster connection only applies to addresses that match the specified `address` field. **An address is matched on the cluster connection when it begins with the string specified in this field**. The `address` field on a cluster connection also supports comma separated lists and an exclude syntax `!`. To prevent an address from being matched on this cluster connection, prepend a cluster connection address string with `!`.

So, by using `#` as the value for `address` you're saying that only addresses that *start with* `#` should be clustered - probably not what you want.  My guess is that you want *all* addresses to be clustered in which case you should just leave `address` empty.  The example from the documentation is empty, and the documentation states:

> In the case shown above the cluster connection will load balance messages sent to all addresses (since it's empty).

Comment: Now it works as expected :) I was pretty sure it had to be some n00b mistake. Thanks a lot for finding it.